# When should I declare abstract methods?

Tags: java, abstraction

I'm currently working on an application that communicates with other applications in the system over different networks. At present, it communicates through [DIS](http://open-dis.sourceforge.net/DIS.html) as well as [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/). Internally, however, the application doesn't care who sent the message or in what format.

With this in mind, I've made an abstract class which contains information called InternalMessage, and an Abstract class for sending and receiving these messages, OrchestrationMessenger. The application polls Messengers for incoming messages and sends responses back. However, the process of sending out messages to the network happens internally to the class and is dependent on the Concrete class that extends InternalMessage.

Should the functions that I know each Concrete class will need, but that will only be used internally, be declared in the Abstract class? I understand *how* to declare the methods, I just don't know if I *should*.

For example: functions that converts incoming messages to my internal format and visa-versa, read incoming messages from the networks, and send the outgoing messages.

The abstract Messenger:

```
//Package omitted
import java.util.Queue;

//Comments omitted
public abstract class OrchestrationMessenger <M extends InternalMessage> implements Runnable
{
    protected Queue<M> incoming, outgoing;

    //Send out a Message, such as responses or commands
    public void publish(M message)
    {
        outgoing.add(message);
    }

    //Receive next incoming Message Object
    public M process()
    {
        return incoming.poll();
    }

    //Check if there are any Messages to process
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return !incoming.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the class `abstract`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The purpose of this family of classes is to listen for messages on DIS, RabbitMQ, or other networks, and then translate that message into a message format used by my application (which does not care what network or process has sent the message). Later, a response may be sent that would be transformed and sent back out to the appropriate network. Each class must: connect to network, handle incoming and outgoing messages simultaneously, and then clean up their connections at shutdown. These things are unique to the network implementation, while the other functions are not.

Comment: I feel as though I have just described the [Template Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method). This is a good indication that I _should_ declare these methods, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should the functions that I know each Concrete class will need, but
>   that will only be used internally, be declared in the Abstract class ?

To answer this you must think whether only the concrete child classes will need this method.

For instance, you have class `Person` and every child class of `Person` need one common method which is say `calculateWeight` which returns the weight of the `Person`. You must say that every `Person` will have same method to do this. However, what about other `Object` say `Animal` which also need the same method to calculate weight of Animals. Note that the requirement of the method is not limited to the sub classes only. Then it should not be in `abstact` class. It should be utility method, otherwise having the common implementation in `abstract` parent is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It dosen't matter if you just use the methods inernally or not to decide, if you should declare them abstract or not.

If every subclass of your abstract class needs this methods, and each has it's specific implementation (so it needs to be implemented in the concrete child classes), then it's probably a good idea to add them as abstract methods to your abstract class.

This way, you can be sure, all you implementations have these methods, which can help you to get a cleaner class model and less redundancy (if not now, then certainly in the future).

Comment: "This way, you can be sure [all your] implementations have these methods[. . .]" This is the crux of the issue for my particular problem. I was uncomfortable with declaring the Abstract methods.Each implementation has to send and receive messages from their networks, but they do this without being prompted, and without returning anything.